# How to change the border of a GroupBox based on the ContentControl tag inside it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am running into a problem with WPF UI wherein I need to set the border of a GroupBox control based on the fact if there is any checkbox inside the GroupBox that has been unchecked. I have tried writing some code but that didn't work, I am new to WPF and I tried using a style to solve the problem but that didn't work well with me. The code looks as follows -:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Header="View Actions" >
            <GroupBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="GroupBox" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ActionsViewModels:IActionViewModel}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </GroupBox.Style>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewActionsVM}"/>
        </GroupBox>
```

Just FYI, the  is used to populate the GroupBox with objects which have a text and checkbox component inside them and look something like this

[image]

Now what I want to be able to do is when one unchecks this checkbox I want to be able to add a red border around the Groupbox in which its contained. The content shown in the image comes from the ContentControl binding that we have in our project. To add to the description of the Content, the content describes an Action to be performed and has a property called as IsEnabled that I am using in the DataTrigger to decide whether to add a border or not.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your XAML but it looks like your view model bindings are all messed up. The GroupBox is binding to some view model and watching its IsEnabled property, but then you're passing a completely different object in as the DataContext to your ContentControl. Try posting your view model code along with exactly how you're binding to it the containing view.

Comment: why have you added d:DataContext to style? what is the DataContext for the groupBox.Also IActionViewModel is set for d:DataContext, thts an interface !!!!